# Include PHP in TWIG

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I configured my Symfony's 2 project for accepting "twig" and "php" extension in "**config.yml**' like that :

```
framework:
router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
    strict_requirements: true
profiler: { only_exceptions: false }    
templating:
    engines: ['twig', 'php']
```

But when i include a php file in twig, it doesn't interpreted PHP:

```
<h1>Reference ROBERT</h1>
<!--?php $name = "Jeremy" ?-->
<h1></h1>
" Hello "
<!--?php echo $name -->
"! "
```

But my php file has no comment. :(

There is another part at configured ?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use php or twig... not php and twig together

Comment: simple actions like setting and writing variables are directly supported in twig, what exactly do you want to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use php in Twig. twig has it's own syntax. Use it or use fully PHP templates!

If you need to call some php functions, write a twig extension.